# Deploying applications created in Visual Studio 2013 on Windows XP

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio, windows-xp

I have created a wpf application using C#.net 4.0.

It has following prerequisites:

```
1. SQL Server Express 2008 R2
2. ReportViewer 2012 
3. Framework 4.0
4. Windows Installer 4.5
```

I have published the one click setup. Now I am trying to install that App on `Windows XP(SP3)`.
But as soon as the setup starts I get an error message for `SQLServerExpressChk.exe` `'Not a valid Win32 application'`.

When googled I read that there was a bug in VS 2012 which produced such behaviour but since Microsoft has fixed the bug such behaviour is strange.

Am I missing here something which I should include in the setup package to make it work?

Comment: It looks like its complaining about the bitness, have you accidently made it a 64bit app?  Try changing all teh build settings to x86.

Comment: all the components are of x86 type only. Also I am getting error while installing the pre-requisite "SQL Server"